# Make Partition for Home inside LVM Volume

Tags: lvm, partition

I have installed (automatically) a Centos7 VM machine inside a Cloud provider which uses VMWare.

I checked the partitions and I realized that the Cloud (VMWare) created two LVM volumes with 2 physical disk:

```
[root@dmz-1 home]# lsblk 
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0   80G  0 disk 
├─sda1           8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2           8:2    0  9,5G  0 part 
│ ├─vg-lv_root 253:0    0 77,4G  0 lvm  /
│ └─vg-lv_swap 253:1    0  2,1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
└─sda3           8:3    0   70G  0 part 
  └─vg-lv_root 253:0    0 77,4G  0 lvm  /
sr0             11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  

[root@dmz-1 home]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 85.9 GB, 85899345920 bytes, 167772160 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Identificativo disco: 0x0009fba7

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1026047      512000   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         1026048    20971519     9972736   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3        20971520   167772159    73400320   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg-lv_root: 83.1 GB, 83126910976 bytes, 162357248 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-lv_swap: 2239 MB, 2239758336 bytes, 4374528 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

[root@dmz-1 home]# df -h
File system             Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
/dev/mapper/vg-lv_root   77G  1,7G     72G   3% /
devtmpfs                2,0G     0    2,0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   2,0G     0    2,0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   2,0G   12M    2,0G   1% /run
tmpfs                   2,0G     0    2,0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1               477M  114M    334M  26% /boot
tmpfs                   395M     0    395M   0% /run/user/0

[root@dmz-1 home]# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  6
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               79,50 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              20353
  Alloc PE / Size       20353 / 79,50 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               gEjaWG-mvkc-k5FD-dtB0-9fA4-4VCY-k5619J
```

Now, I'd like to move the `/home` to a new partition. Where shall I create the partion? And how? With fdisk?

Comment: Add the result of `vgdisplay`. Your volume group seems pretty full at first sight.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz done. So I can't create a new partition inside the LVM? Or maybe my question is a non-sense in the LVM context, isn'it?

Comment: Your question makes perfect sense, but your volume group is full. If you don't want to add more disk space, you'll have to shrink some other partition.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the whole available space in the volume group (VG) is assigned to the root filesystem, so you'll have to **shrink** `/dev/mapper/vg-lv_root` first.

Shrinking may be problematic, since you need to:

1. Unmount the filesystem. Since it is your root filesystem, you'll have to use some kind of rescue environment offered by your cloud provider.
2. Shrink the filesystem:

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg-lv_root 10G
   ```
3. Shrink the logical volume:

   ```
   lvreduce -L 10G vg/lv_root
   ```
4. I don't remember if resize2fs units are 1000 based or 1024 base, maybe you need to extend your filesystem to fit the logical volume:

   ```
   resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg-lv_root
   ```

All this must be done in some **rescue** environment, since unmounting the root filesystem is not possible.

After all of this you can create a new logical volume:

```
lvcreate -L 10G vg -n lv_home
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/mapper/vg-lv_root
```

I used 10 gibibytes as example size. When choosing the size of your partition, try to find a compromise between the risk of finding your filesystem full and the risk of having to shrink another filesystem. You can grow filesystems without unmounting them.